# Why are Html Entities replaced by MS Expression Web?

Tags: html, special-characters, html-entities, expression-web

I'm using Microsofts Expression Web 5 to edit my HTML documents. I have noticed a strange behaviour when using the 'Reformat HTML' method.

If my html document (UTF-8) contains html entities in the like of € the entity is replaced by a euro character. The html entities with a special meaning like '<' and '>' will not be replaced. So '<' (read: ampersand-l-t-semicolon) is left untouched.

Why does Expression Web do this?? I'm pretty sure it's best practise to use html entities whenever you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Expression Web do this?? I'm pretty sure it's best practise to use html entities whenever you can.

Actually, no: In a UTF-8 document, it's fine to use proper UTF-8 characters over HTML entities.

So, what Expression Web is okay (Although this is a feature one should be able to turn off somewhere).

Related discussion:

- [When Should One Use HTML Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities)
- [Should I still use html entities? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520236/should-i-still-use-html-entities-why)

Answer (score 0):

There's no Expression Web 5 (version 4 is the latest).

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Presumably I used Expression Web 4. I have since re-installed my PC so can't check. But there's definitely no version 5 at this time!

Answer (score 0):

Actually all you need to do is:

1. Tools > Page Editor Options
2. Go to Default Fonts tab
3. Change the language to Unicode (UTF-8)
4. Click OK
5. Close and reopen the HTML file

That will do it.

Comment: Hi Perjan, Thanks for your answer. I re-installed Expression Web 4 and could not replicate the original behavior I had trouble with. So for now I could not try your solution.